# Unexpected result of size_t modulo long unsigned int

Tags: c

In the following code, `BITS_IN_INT` is an `long unsigned int` with value `32`. Why does the modulo operation return the value `0` instead of the expected `20`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define BITS_IN_INT sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT

int main()
{
    size_t i = 20;

    printf("%zu\n", i);
    printf("%lu\n", BITS_IN_INT);
    printf("%lu\n", i % BITS_IN_INT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because of the lack of parentheses. The expanded code is `i % sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT`

Comment: It should be `#define BITS_IN_INT (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)`

Comment: The preprocessor performs textual replacement of the macros. Remove the  `#define BITS_IN_INT`, replace `BITS_IN_INT` by `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` and read your code again and it should be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After macro expansion, the last printf looks like:

```
printf("%lu\n", i % sizeof(int) * 8);
```

So, the expression (in printf) is evaluated as if:

```
(i % sizeof(int)) * 8
```

If `sizeof(int)` is 4 (which seems to the case on your platform) then `i % sizeof(int)` yields 0; `0 * 8` is `0`.

Avoid macros if you can. If not, always use parentheses around your macros:

```
#define BITS_IN_INT (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)
```

NB: `%zu` is the correct format specifier for printing `size_t` values.